# Is it possible to install a custom Linux on an Android phone?

Tags: linux, arm, android

I have an Xperia X8 phone, and I'd like to know if I can install a non-Android Linux OS on it?
I would like to have a light Linux Distro, like Kolibri or something like that.

Comment: I think you should probably ask on the Android Q&A site, as people there are much more likely to know about specific phones. You might enjoy reading this anyway: http://www.android-devs.com/?p=152

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to get a custom Linux running on an embedded device, in general:

1. Search the web for projects describing how to port some distro to *exeactly* the device in question. If you find it and it looks well described, you're a happy person :) My tip here: Look at success stories first! See what actually *can be done* (what final functionality did people get).
2. Advanced: use generic porting procedures, such as described [here](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-arm.xml). You will need to do a research on your own, to find out what peripherals are supported, where and how to get drivers for them etc. One thing's for certain: **You *will* need to build custom kernel for that** and most often it will include getting a specific kernel version and a lot of patching. In many situations, there might be a high risk of bricking your device involved.

There is also [Ångström Linux](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) project that aims at porting Linux to different machines. Use it's [online system builder](http://narcissus.angstrom-distribution.org/) to create a custom distribution - **if** you find that the *machine* is supported.

Always remember that in majority of cases *at least* some parts of the hardware will not be (yet) supported. **Always have a close look at what's achievable before you start.**

---

One might also take a different approach to the "Advanced" option, specifically in the case of Android-based devices: Since the given device runs a Linux-like kernel, you can use it with all the ready modules etc. But then you'll have to adapt the standard Linux userspace programs to play nicely with the not-really-linux core.